# How to respond "say hello to somebody"?

Tags: greetings

One of my previous professors emailed me and at the end he asked me to say hello to my mom.
I am wondering how to reply him ? Is "Thank you, she say hi back to you" sounds correct?

Comment: Yes, except that it should be _she says hi_.

Comment: Oh, yes, that was a typo. Many thanks for you answer